# How do i get my ID to hover over the div that the id is referenced to

Tags: javascript, css

The code create div's which are square black boxes. 
When hovering over a square, the value of the square's id should display centered in the square, and disappear when the cursor is no longer over the square. - any ideas how to accomplish this?

```
let button = document.createElement("button")
let text = document.createTextNode("Add Squares")
let num = 1;
let displayText = document.createTextNode("num");



button.appendChild(text);


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.body.appendChild(button);
});


button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let test = document.createElement("div")
    test.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    test.style.width = "77px";
    test.style.height = "77px";
    test.style.display = "inline-block";
    test.className = "squares";
    test.id = num;
    console.log(num)
    onMouseover="displayQuote();" 
    num++;
    document.body.appendChild(test);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS can handle that for you with the use of a pseudo-element loading in the `id` attribute (and `opacity` change on `:hover` — you could also change `display` instead, if you wanted):

```js
let button = document.createElement("button")
let text = document.createTextNode("Add Squares")
let num = 1;
let displayText = document.createTextNode("num");



button.appendChild(text);


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.body.appendChild(button);
});


button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let test = document.createElement("div")
    // Styles moved to CSS
    test.className = "squares";
    test.id = num;
    console.log(num)
    num++;
    document.body.appendChild(test);
});
```

```css
.squares {
  background-color: black;
  width: 77px;
  height: 77px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  position: relative;
}

.squares::after {
  content: attr(id);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
}

.squares:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. create a child div of the black div
2. add id to the child div
3. make the child div display: none
4. use CSS rule to display child div on :hover

Example:

```css
body {
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 1rem;
}

/* the black squares */
.squares {
  background-color: black;
  width: 77px;
  height: 77px;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* transparent overlay with ID */
.overlay {
  background: transparent;
  width: 77px;
  height: 77px;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}

/* show overlay on hover */
.squares:hover .overlay {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="10" class="squares">
    <div class="overlay"><p>10</p></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is to use CSS. It can be easily done by CSS. But you might need it for some specific case. Here is the code you should use to achieve your goal.

```js
let button = document.createElement("button");
let text = document.createTextNode("Add Squares");
let num = 1;
let displayText = document.createTextNode("num");

button.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(button);
document.body.style.cssText = 'display:flex; align-items:flex-start;';

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let styles = {
        'width': '77px',
        'height': '77px',
        'background-color': 'black',
        'color': 'white',
        'display': 'flex',
        'align-items': 'center',
        'justify-content': 'center',
    }

    let div = document.createElement("div")
    div.id = num;
    div.className = "squares";
    for (let style in styles) {
        div.style[style] = styles[style];
    }
    div.onmouseover = function() {
        document.getElementById('text'+this.id).style.display = 'block';
    }
    div.onmouseout = function() {
        document.getElementById('text'+this.id).style.display = 'none';
    }

    let text = document.createElement('span');
    text.id = 'text'+num;
    text.style.display = 'none';
    text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(num));

    div.appendChild(text);
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    num++;
});
```